# /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php': free() - Error

Tags: php, xml, dom, compiler-errors, simplexml

I get this error:
[(because of char limitations on pastebin.com)](https://pastebin.com/5E11vT52)

And I know that I get this error only because I want to make a triangle replacement. I know that because before I implement the triangle replacement, everything worked fine...

What I want to do is to get all `price` and `price_base` tags and swap them. But I do not know why PHP is complaining about that...

Here is the code:

```
function specialPriceToPrice($dom, $path ,$price, $specialPrice)
{

    $doc = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    $items = $doc->xpath("//$path");
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($item);

        $tmp = $node->getElementsByTagName($specialPrice)->item(0)->textContent;

        if($tmp != ""){
            $tmp2 = $node->getElementsByTagName($price)->item(0)->textContent;
            $node->getElementsByTagName($price)->item(0)->textContent = $tmp;
            $node->getElementsByTagName($specialPrice)->item(0)->textContent = $tmp2;

            $tmp = null;
            $tmp2 = null;
        }

        $node = null;
        $tmp = null;
        $tmp2 = null;
        $item = null;
    }

    $doc = null;
    $items = null;
}
```

I also tried `$tmp != null`- but same result...
Can it be that this error comes up because of the feed?

Because sometimes I have a `price_base` which looks like this `<price_base/>` but it could also be that it looks like `<price_base></price_base>`. And of course, sometimes it's filled 13.13.

[Here is the raw feed](http://j-trier.de/cronjob/data/raw/gamebillet.xml) (I rename `special_price` to `price_base`)

http: //j-trier.de/cronjob/data/gamebillet.xml (Not allowed more then 2 links)

Could the error because in my output feed the `price_base` ends with `/` and not starts with `/`?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is better or worse for you, but that error is not PHP complaining about your code, it's actually crashing, hard. That is to say, it's a bug in PHP itself (or one of the libraries it's built out of). If you can, try running the identical PHP code under a newer version of PHP. If it's not fixed in a newer build, it's something that should be raised on https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: But a bug on a triangle change?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "triangle change". It's definitely a bug, because PHP is internally accessing memory in an incorrect way; it might be triggered by something unusual in your XML, but it's not going to be something really common, otherwise lots of people would have seen it, and it would be fixed by now.